# Breaking apart the surface tension of a water droplet

Tags: water, surface-tension

How far apart do two vertical glass surfaces have to stand for a water droplet that is sticking to both of them to break into two?

I apologize in advance for the question possibly being too imprecise .

Comment: Thanks!  I did eventually conduct a small experiment, which gave me a distance of just under 3mm. But it’d be nice to have it confirmed with math & a proper scientific explanation.

Comment: I'm also excited to see an answer. I expect the approach will be related to the variational approach used to analyze the [Rayleigh instability point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh_instability) (i.e., at some point perturbations decrease the surface area rather than increasing it), but I'm not a pro at this approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a [capillary bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_bridges) will break when either surface tension overcomes adhesion or when gravity overcomes them both.  For water, we expect the bridge to break before it separates by a distance roughly equal to the diameter of a spherical drop having the same volume as the bridge.

As shown in this [diagram from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Relation_of_liquid_static_capillary_bridge_dimensionless_height_and_dimensionless_radius_in_cylindrical_coordinates.jpg), for a water and glass bridge will have a concave shape.

[image: Concave capillary bridge schematic representation]

**Ignoring Gravity**

For a drop of water with constant volume $V$, the contact radius $R$ and the waist radius $r_m$ of the bridge shrink as the plate separation $H$ increases until the bridge breaks.  We can estimate a rough upper limit on $H$ by comparing the water surface energy ($2 \pi r_\mathrm{cyl} \sigma)$ of a cylindrical bridge  to the surface energy ($4\pi r_{\mathrm{sph}}^2 \sigma$) of a spherical drop with the same volume. The surface tension $\sigma$ drops out and we find that converting to a spherical drop is energetically favourable where $H\gtrsim 2 r_{\mathrm{sph}} = (6V/\pi)^{1/3}\approx 1.2 V^{1/3}$.

We can get a more precise answer from this [Wikipedia diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_bridges#Definition_domain) (original from [Petkov & Radoev](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.colsurfa.2014.03.038)) showing the relationship between where $R^*\equiv R/V^{1/3}$ and $H^*\equiv H/V^{1/3}$:
[image]

The different curves correspond to different [contact angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) $\theta$. For perfectly clean smooth silica glass, the contact angle for pure water [can be close to](https://doi.org/10.1039/B308125G)  $0^\circ$, but contact angles up to almost $60^\circ$ can be [found online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contact+angle%22+%22water%22+glass%22) for less clean, less smooth, or otherwise different glass/water interfaces. We can see that for a cylindrical bridge ($\theta \sim 90^\circ$), our rough estimate of $H^*_\mathrm{max}\sim 1.2$ is pretty close.  For the smallest contact angle ($\theta= 1^\circ$), $H^*_\mathrm{max}\sim 0.5$.

**Effect of Gravity**

Using dimensional analysis (as in ["Gravity vs adhesion of a water droplet"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778095/145491)), we expect gravity to break the bridge if the separation distance is

$$H\gtrsim \left(\frac{\sigma}{\rho g}\right)^{1/2}$$

where $\sigma$ is the [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension),  $\rho$ is the density of the drop, and $g\approx 9.81\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ is the acceleration due to gravity.  For water at $20$°C, $\sigma\approx 72.8\,\mathrm{N/m}$ and $\rho\approx 1000\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$, giving

$$H_\mathrm{max}\sim 3\,\mathrm{mm}$$

This means that to study really large capillary bridges, you'd need to book time on the [vomit comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft) or the [ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station).

Comment: I absolutely love the way you analyzed the question - thank you so much! ☺️ I can assure you that this question has a purpose, I'm designing a component in fusion 360 that interacts with water and I need to keep the water from sticking to both ends.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the droplet creates a [minimal surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) where the [contact angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) is tangential to this minimal surface.

Thus this question can not be answered before this contact angle of the glass is defined. The breaking will nevertheless happen in the [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) of this shape.