# Gravity vs adhesion of a water droplet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, water, surface-tension, adhesion

How much volume can a water droplet that is attached to a vertical glass surface have before it begins to roll downwards?

Comment: Liquid or solid water? Kind of tongue in cheek, but also there isn't one single answer to this because the glass side has an impact as well.

Comment: Well, liquid water, I think. By ‘solid water’, did you mean ice? Sorry if my question isn’t descriptive enough - I’d be perfectly happy with a formula rather than a literal value.

Comment: In theory, a droplet of *any* size will spontaneously slide down on an idealized uniform vertical surface because there's no reason for it not to. In practice, the surface presentation (including the surface energy and topography) of the wall will vary, and there will be kinetic limitations to the rate of bond detachment, and there will be impurities on the wall that may or may not dissolve in the water. All this introduces additional phenomena and stochasticity. It's not clear what aspects you're interested in. Please clarify.

Comment: I am voting to reopen since this is a nice example of interesting everyday physics, and I am not sure that adding additional details would significantly improve the question. Yes, the OP could have specified a drop of pure liquid water at room temperature and pressure on clean common window glass, but this doesn't greatly affect the answer for any reasonable assumptions.   I have added some discussion of the effect of possible contaminants to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on the purity of the water, the temperature of the water, the temperature of the glass, the type of glass and its surface texture and cleanliness. It could depend on the relative humidity.  Sounds like a fun experiment!

We can also make some rough theoretical estimates.  Using dimensional analysis, we expect the critical volume where the drop will start to move to be of order
$$V_c\sim \left(\frac{\sigma}{\rho g}\right)^{3/2}$$
where $\sigma$ is the [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension),  $\rho$ is the density of the drop, and $g\approx 9.81\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$ is the acceleration due to gravity.  For water at $20$°C, $\sigma\approx 72.8\,\mathrm{N/m}$ and $\rho\approx 1000\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$, giving

$$V_c\sim 20\,\mathrm{\mu L}$$

More precise modelling requires knowing the [contact angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle)  of the bottom and top of the drop which tell us about the water-glass [adhesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesion), e.g. see ["On the ability of drops or bubbles to stick to non-horizontal surfaces of solids"](https://doi.org/10.1017/S002211208300227X). A study of ["Drops at Rest on a Tilted Plane"](https://doi.org/10.1021/la970645l) gave values in the range of $10-20\,\mathrm{\mu L}$ for the 90° critical angle for pure water on glass substrates treated in different ways. I'd estimate slightly smaller values ($\sim 5\,\mathrm{\mu L}$) from a quick experiment with my hand mirror, but it is pretty warm and humid.

This all assumes a drop of pure liquid water at room temperature and pressure on clean common window glass, but the results are reasonably robust to small variations.

[Water surface tension varies](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-surface-tension-d_597.html) by only about 20% from 0 to 100°C, and liquid water's density varies by only about 4%.  Adding salts [increases the surface tension](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0662656.pdf) and decreases adhesion. A saturated aqueous NaCl solution has surface tension about 15% higher.
The [contact angle increases](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221954230_On_the_influence_of_sodium_chloride_concentration_on_equilibrium_contact_angle) from 40° for pure water to 55° for saturated aqueous NaCl solution on microscope cover glass, or from 48° to 76° for commercial glass. (The bigger the angle, the [bigger the ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting#Explanation) of surface tension to adhesion.)

[Surfactants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfactant) have a more significant effects, however, with common detergents  [lowering surface tension by up to a factor of 3](https://www.ebatco.com/industries-applications/household-products-and-cosmetics/), so the glass needs to be very well rinsed after cleaning. Since detergent is extremely [hydrophilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophile), if a thin layer is left on the glass, this could also effectively increase the adhesion since the water sticks to the detergent and the detergent sticks to the glass.